# How to configure mounted FTP connection

Tags: centos, ftp, nautilus

I'm using latest CentOS with Gnome, and using bookmarked FTP connection, that connects to my server, and mounts remote directory. The thing is, I see no way to configure that FTP client, whatever that is. I get timeout's too often, and annoying popup of that, makes me do submit changes twice.

So, question: how to configure integrated filesystem FTP connection/mounting tool, to set up some sort of connection keep-alive.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Nautilus' integrated FTP client stuff, one option would be switching to another FTP-filesystem solution, e.g. [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) which is based on FUSE (and seems to be packaged for CentOS), and might help, since it

> automatically reconnect[s] if the server times out

[See its man page for options.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curlftpfs)  Anyway, I guess its integration into you graphical user interface naturally lags behind Nautilus' integrated FTP client (i.e., if something fails expect non-descriptive error messages from Nautilus).